# SVG stroke animation not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animations, stroke

My JS code goes over each path, and adds a `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` according to path length:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    const $paths = document.getElementsByTagName('path');
    for (const path of $paths) {
        const totalLength = path.getTotalLength();
        path.style.strokeDashoffset = totalLength;
        path.style.strokeDasharray = totalLength;
    }
}, 300);
```

Then, My CSS just animates the `dashoffset` to `0`, while lowering the stroke opacity and raising the fill opacity:

```
.character path {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke: white;
    -webkit-animation: path 4s linear 1s both;
            animation: path 4s linear 1s both;
}

@keyframes path {
    70% {
        fill-opacity: 0;
    }

    80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-opacity: 1;
        
    }

    100% {
        stroke-opacity: 0;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        fill-opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly in Chrome - the animation shows the paths being drawn, **but in Safari, the paths just show up without any animation.**
I tried prefixing but it doesn't work.
EDIT: This is somehow related to the timeout I set, I just added it to the code of the question. I have to add that timeout because the svg is loaded dynamically.
Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1n5m7k0t/) showing the problem (works in Chrome, not in Safari), thanks @kaiido.

Comment: What version of Safari? [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fk9qLcwe/) works exactly the same in my Safari 15.4 than in my Chrome v100

Comment: That's really weird. Your fiddle works for me too. My problem is probably in something else in the code

Comment: @Kaiido I updated the question with the problem, you can now see it in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing two things:

1. Put the `animation` property in the JS as well
2. I found out that Safari doesn't handle animations in `setTimeout` if the animation delay is larger than the timeout. So I lowered the delay to 200ms.

Updated JS:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    const $paths = document.getElementsByTagName('path');
    for (const path of $paths) {
        const totalLength = path.getTotalLength();
        path.style.strokeDashoffset = totalLength;
        path.style.strokeDasharray = totalLength;
        path.style.animation = 'path 4s linear 0.2s both';
  };
}, 300);
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzx45h7r/)